# I am having trouble using preferences with libgdx. not saving high score?

Tags: java, android, save, libgdx, preferences

i am having trouble with preferences. I am trying to save the high score using libgdx on to the phone. It works WHEN THE APP IS RUNNING, but when i close the app the high score is not saved!

```
if(currentScore > highscore){
    highscore = currentScore;

    prefs.putInteger("score", highscore);

    getHighScore =prefs.getInteger("highscore", highscore);
    highScore = ("high score: " + getHighScore);
    prefs.flush();
}
```

I don't know why it is not saving the highscore. Any help would be appreceiated. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the full code about the preferences when you get or put something in it?

Comment: "score" != "highscore"?  (You're writing to 'score' but checking 'highscore'?)

Comment: i am setting the value of highscore to current score.

Comment: Why can't i do that. It is working, it is just that when the app is fully quit then the highscore is not saved, which is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
prefs.putInteger("score", highscore);
```

with

```
prefs.putInteger("highscore", highscore);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.